# Parse Android SDK - Querying based on Pointer in Android SDK

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

*The current questions on the internet about this didn't help (it's no duplicate).*

Currently I'm experimenting with the `GameScore` example class.
Simply searching for a value in a column (here it's 1337 in the column "score") was as easy as this (in **Kotlin**):

```kotlin
val query = ParseQuery<ParseObject>("GameScore")
query.whereEqualTo("score", 1337)
query.findInBackground { objects, e ->
    ...
}
```

---

Then I wanted to implement a query to search for a value in an Array a pointer points to (based on [THIS ARTICLE](https://designingforscale.com/query-on-a-parse-pointer/)). For easier understand I just used the classes shown [in the article](https://designingforscale.com/query-on-a-parse-pointer/).

He tells us that in **Javascript** you can do that with following code:

```js
var visitQuery = new Parse.Query('Visit');  
visitQuery.equalTo('user', { "__type": "Pointer", "className": "_User", "objectId": userId });  
return visitQuery.find();
```

Here you search for those objects of the `Visit` class which have the `userId` as their `objectId`.

---

So how do you convert that pointer query to Kotlin for the Android SDK? I currently don't know how to do this with Kotlin / Java syntax.

And if you achieve to execute that search succesfully, how can you seach for a value in a Array if the pointer points to an Array in the `Visit` class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `whereMatchesQuery` function. More details in [this](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#relational-queries) link. It will be something like the code below.

```kotlin
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query("InnerClass");
innerQuery.whereEqualTo("someField", "someValue");
var query = new Parse.Query("OuterClass");
query.whereMatchesQuery("someArrayField", innerQuery);
```

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems this is Java code but it should be same as Kotlin.
I think currently it's `ParseQuery.getQuery("Class")` rather than `Parse.Query("Class")`, right?

Comment: For me the `Parse` class does not have any subclasses except `Configuration`

Comment: Sorry. It's new `ParseQuery("ClassName")`.